# $inc follower count, or should I use an aggregate to track them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I"m loading products via an infinite scroll in chunks of 12 at a time.

At times, I may want to sort these by how many followers they have.

Below is how i'm tracking how many followers each product has.

---

Follows are in a separate collection, because of the 16mb data cap, and the amount of follows should be unlimited.

follow schema:

```
var FollowSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    product: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product'
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

Product that is followed schema:

```
var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    followers: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});
```

Whenever a user follows / unfollows a product, I run this function:

```
ProductSchema.statics.updateFollowers = function (productId, val) {
    return Product
        .findOneAndUpdateAsync({
            _id: productId
        }, {
            $inc: {
                'followers': val
            }
        }, {
            upsert: true,
            'new': true
        })
        .then(function (updatedProduct) {
            return updatedProduct;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Product follower update err : ', err);
        })
};
```

My questions about this:

1: Is there a chance that the incremented "follower" value within product could hit some sort of error, resulting in un matching / inconsistent data?

2: would it be better to write an aggregate to count followers for each Product, or would that be too expensive / slow?

Eventually, I'll probably rewrite this in a graphDB, as it seems better suited, but for now -- this is an exercise in mastering MongoDB.

Comment: About #1: A single document update is atomic, but you are updating 2 documents in 2 collections which isn't overall atomic. It might be that either of the steps fail. For example, follow was a success but increment failed. Read: [Two phased commits.](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 If you increment after inserting or decrement after removing, these is a chance resulting in inconsistent data. For example, insertion succeed but incrementing failed.

2 Intuitively, aggregation is much more expensive than find in this case. I did a benchmark to prove it.

First generate 1000 users, 1000 products and 10000 followers randomly. Then, use this code to benchmark.

```
import timeit

from pymongo import MongoClient
db = MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test', tz_aware=True).get_default_database()

def foo():
    result = list(db.products.find().sort('followers', -1).limit(12).skip(12))

def bar():
    result = list(db.follows.aggregate([
        {'$group': {'_id': '$product', 'followers': {'$sum': 1}}},
        {'$sort': {'followers': -1}},
        {'$skip': 12},
        {'$limit': 12}
    ]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = timeit.timeit('foo()', 'from __main__ import foo', number=100)
    print('time: %f' % t)

    t = timeit.timeit('bar()', 'from __main__ import bar', number=100)
    print('time: %f' % t)
```

output:

```
time: 1.230138
time: 3.620147
```

Creating index can speed up find query.

```
db.products.createIndex({followers: 1})

time: 0.174761
time: 3.604628
```

And If you need attributes from product such as name, you need another O(n) query.

I guess that when data scale up, aggregation will be much more slow. If need, I can benchmark on big scale data.

Answer (score 0):

For number 1, if the only operations on that field are incrementing and decrementing, I think you'd be okay. If you start replicating that data or using it in joins for some reason, you'd run the risk of inconsistent data.

For number 2, I'd recommend you run both scenarios in the mongo shell to test them out. You can also [review the individual explain plans](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/) for both queries to get an idea of which one would perform better. I'm just guessing, but it seems like the update route would perform well.

Also, the amount of expected data makes a difference. It might intially perform well one way, but after a million records the other route might be the way to go. If you have a test environment, that'd be a good thing to check.

Answer (score 0):

1) This relies on the application layer to enforce consistency, and as such there is going to be a chance that you end up with inconsistencies.  The questions I would ask are: how important is consistency in this case, and how likely is it that there will be a large inconsistency?  My thought is that being off by one follower isn't as important as making your infinite scroll load as fast as possible to improve the user's experience.

2) Probably worth looking at the performance, but if I had to guess I would say this approach is going to be to slow.